# form element is not valid

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm trying to make a form (without using django's template forms) but for some reason my forms are never valid when I try them. Here is my code:

forms.py:

```
class AddressForm(forms.Form):
    address_long = forms.CharField(max_length=500)

    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = ['address_long']

    def save(self, commit=True):
        address = Address.objects.create()
        address.address_long = self.cleaned_data['address_long']
        
        if commit:
            address.save()

        return address
```

views.py:

```
@login_required
def add_address_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddressForm(request.POST)
        print(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("Valid")
            address = form.save()
            user_profile = request.user.userprofile
            user_profile.addresses.add(address) # Add to many to many field
            user_profile.save() 

            return redirect('core:profile')  # Redirect to the user's profile page
    else:
        form = AddressForm()

    return render(request, 'Test_site/add-address.html', {'form': form, 'countries': COUNTRIES})
```

And my html looks like this:

```
...
<form method="POST" class="col-md-5 border-right">
   {% csrf_token %}
   ...
   <div class="col-md-12">
      <label class="labels">Address Long</label>
      <input name="{{ form.address_long.name }}" id="{{ form.address_long.auto_id }}"  type="text" class="input-field form-control" placeholder="enter address line" value="">
   </div>
   ...   
</form>
```

When I try this on my local host I get this output from the print statements in the view function:

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['my_generated_token'], 'address_long': ['Long address try']}>
```

But no matter what I do it just doesn't pass the '.is_valid()' check. Also I can't look up on what 'form' holds, like trying to do `form.cleaned_data['address_long']` causes a 'form doesnt have member cleaned_data' error. It acts like it can't create the object. For example form.address_long is also invalid, eventhough I've created the form, it says it's not there.

What's the issue here?

Note: I have more members in AddressForm then address_long, but they are all char fields and I made sure all the fields are filled on every step.

Answer (score 0):

You could let the view handle the form by simply posting the form data and getting the fileds since you are passing an empty form.. In that case, your code would look like below.

views.py:

```
@login_required
def add_address_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        address_long = request.POST.get("address-long")
        form = AddressForm(address_long = address_long)
        print(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("Valid")
            address = form.save()
            user_profile = request.user.userprofile
            user_profile.addresses.add(address) # Add to many to many field
            user_profile.save() 

            return redirect('core:profile')  # Redirect to the user's profile page
    

    return render(request, 'Test_site/add-address.html', {'countries': COUNTRIES})
```

And my html looks like this:

```
...
<form method="POST" class="col-md-5 border-right">
   {% csrf_token %}
   ...
   <div class="col-md-12">
      <label class="labels">Address Long</label>
      <input name="address-long"  class="input-field form-control" placeholder="enter address line" value="">
   </div>
   ...   
</form>
```

Comment: This might work, but I still don't get why my implementation is faulty.

Comment: Might be because you are trying to access fields of an empty form  in your html.

Comment: I literally check request.POST and everything is fine